# Facebook Comments sometimes not loading

Tags: facebook-comments

I kindly ask you to advise why Facebook Comments sometimes do not appear on my site.

I use standard code generated from Facebook Developers site.

Please note that the Comments box is located under the colored frame. Usually, it appears after reloading the page. Real site examples:

http://wakemovies.com/?ND201206190204

http://wakemovies.com/?BL201206190157

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly Facebook  comments require a bit of customization to the dock-type they have special format.
You should add this line tou your dock type

```
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
```

One more thing you are overloading your page with Facebook like buttons. I think one is more than enough considering most people have sharing plugins installed int they browsers.

Comment: I have added xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml", unfortunatelly problem persists. Like buttons are used deliberately as they are. Please help.

Comment: Clear cache from your browser because I can comment on your given examples.

Comment: I have checked on another PC and problem persists. Tricky part is that sometimes (or after reloading the page) they will appear. Please try another page: http://wakemovies.com/?FS201206140141 or select "Comment" on any movies from main listening on www.wakemovies.com

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a setTimeout with a delay of 1 second

example:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // Your Facebook Comments JavaScript Code Here
}, 1000);
```